# Is it possible to component be delayed to be destroyed in React?

Tags: reactjs

The scene is:

`{bool && <MyComponent />`

is it possible to delay destruction of the `<MyComponent />` when bool is false? I tried using

`useEffect(() => () => delayFunc())`

inside MyComponent but it does not work.

Comment: Can you explain more, why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a state to your component.

```
{boolState && <MyComponent />
```

And update this state in the `useEffect` after `bool` is changed.